# window.setTimeout doesn't read the correct values

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is the code

```
var _d=1000;
for(var ii=0; ii<4; ii+=1){
    console.log(_d*ii);
    window.setTimeout(applyState(ii,_d),_d*ii);
}
```

I want the applyState() function to be called 4 time with 1 second of delay between them, What really happens is that all are called at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` operator calls the function, you should pass the function itself, otherwise the returned value of function is passed to the `setTimeout` function. But this won't solve the issue completely. `for` block doesn't create a new scope. You can use a self-invoking function:

```
var _d=1000;
for(var ii=0; ii<4; ii+=1){
    (function(a) {
         console.log(_d * a);
         window.setTimeout(function() {
            applyState(a,_d);
          },_d*a);    
    })(ii);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a function to setTimeout, you're currently passing the return value of applyState(ii, _d)

try

```
window.setTimeout(function(){applyState(ii, _d);}, _d*ii)
```

unless applyState doesn't actually need the arguments in which case you can just use

```
window.setTimeout(applyState, _d*ii)
```

Comment: but like so it won't recognize my variables ii , _d